# Macbook cannot see specific wireless network after being connected to it for a while

Tags: macos, mac, wireless-networking, airport

Okay, so there's a single wireless network that my laptop has troubles with. My Macbook Pro used to be fine with it until it changed to using channel 13 (or 11?). Since then, after being connected to it for a while it disappears from my laptop's view. Other networks are showing up fine and other computers (including several Macs) have no troubles connecting to this network. If I clear my system cache using [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/pgs/english/apps.html) and then restart (sometimes a couple times) my laptop can see and connect to it again. But it seems that if I disconnect and try reconnecting I have to clear my cache again.

One thing to note is that if I put my computer to sleep while connected to this network it has no problems reconnecting on wake up.

I've got a 15" Macbook Pro 2,2 with Leopard 10.5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, it turns out it was because I had [Safe Eyes](http://www.internetsafety.com/safe-eyes-parental-control-software.php) installed. Uninstalling it seems to have fixed the problem.

I found this out because I temporarily moved to a different laptop (Macbook) while my Macbook Pro, that was exhibiting the problems, got repaired for a separate reason. This Macbook had been connecting just fine to the problem router but since I setup my account and installed Safe Eyes it could no longer see the network. After uninstalling it, there seems to be no problems.

Safe Eyes is a parental control program and digs its roots deep into your system (the only program I use that does so) which might explain why it was causing problems. Now, why it was just this specific network and not others, I have no idea. But, problem solved. I may contact Safe Eyes support to report this problem and see if there are any known solutions, but that can wait until I have more time.

Comment: Well done - bit of a struggle, but I'm glad its fixed.
Never come across this before!

Answer (score 1):

If it happened just after a channel change (it is your network isn't it? - you change the channel at the router rather than at the Mac) it might just be interference which would give the intermittent problems you seem to be seeing. The distinguishable channels are something like 1, 6 and 13.  If you have control of the router you could change the channel.

Sometimes it's not even other networks, you could be seeing interference from Microwaves and the like.

Comment: This is a router in an office about 20 people all with computers connected via wifi to the same router. They are having no problems at all. It's only my computer. And, my computer does connect fine if I clear the system cache and restart. But after a while it has troubles again. Please see my question for more info. Thanks!

Comment: OK, its definitely your machine - I suspect corrupt preference files.
Download Cocktail and check for corrupt preference files, delete as appropriate.  Don't think Onyx does this.
If that doesn't work, your airport card could be faulty - run the extended hardware test (hold down 'd' and reboot with system disks in drive).
Is it just the one network you have problems with?  Can you find another network, set it to channel 13 and see if you have the same problems?  That would eliminate the possibility that it's just the one router.  Details of the network might help, too - encyyption etc.

Comment: I've tried Cocktail, running an extended hardware test, and changing another router to channel 13 all to no avail. My computer is able to connect to the other router just fine. The problem router is encrypted by WPA2 Personal but not the other router I tried. I'll try that soon.

Comment: I suspect this is an intermittent hardware fault - can you reseat the airport card or take it to an Apple Store and get them to either reseat or replace card.  AEHT sometimes struggles to pick up intermittent faults.

Comment: I suspect you mean "reset" and not "reseat" and "AHT" and not "AEHT", right?  Let me know if I'm wrong and please explain what you mean in that case. Is there a way I can manually reset my Airport card? I changed the encryption method on the non-problem router and it's been working fine for a couple days now. Thank you for your help in this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: No, by 're-seat' I mean plug in and out again, in case there's some grot stuck in the pins 

or socket.  You would need to take the case apart, so it depends on how handy you are.  

iFixit.comn  is good for this. If it's under warranty, I'd get Apple to switch the Airport 

card. By AEHT, I just meant Apple Extended Hardware TEST - running the test with the box 

ticked for a full set of tests - it can sometimes miss intermittent faults.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser - so its just a problem on a specific router at a specific frequency?  Does anyone else in the office have a Macbook? It starts to look like the router again!

Since there's a limit to what you can do with the router try these:
Is the rest of your machine in tip top shape - you've run Disk Utility etc to verify/ repair disk and repaired permissions?  They can sometimes cause strange effects.

I take it you can't get near an ethernet cable/ port?

Comment: Well, I've done everything you recommended aside from re-seating/replacing the card. There are several others with Macbooks in this office. I think one is even the same model as mine. And otherwise my laptop is in tip top shape. I can't get an ethernet port plugged in. And yes, it's just this specific router. Haven't noticed any troubles with any other routers. And as far as I know it was only the channel that changed (from 11, I think) and nothing else. Before that change I was able to connect just fine.

Comment: Well OK, this is the Apple site airport troubleshooting.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1145#trouble

I quote from a linked page:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1401?viewlocale=en_US

"Is just one client affected?
If so, concentrate on troubleshooting client settings on that computer. Make sure that its AirPort card is properly installed, with the antenna connected."

So I think you need to get your airport card looked at.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I'll do it on the last day of my warranty, this Saturday :P It's weird because I don't have troubles with any other networks (at least that I know of) and I can see many other networks while this problematic one is invisible to my computer. Thanks so much for the help. I really appreciate you keeping up with this.

Comment: Intermittent hardware faults can be really difficult to diagnose, the router probably broadcasts a slightly higher frequency than normal (there's a little bit of variation in each unit) and the card probably struggles a bit more than normal.

If you can print out any error messages or console logs that might help demonstrate you have a problem to the genius at the store.
Let me know how you get on.

Are you at the one year mark or have you bought Applecare - might be worth considering - faults rarely travel alone!

Comment: I'm on the end of my Applecare plan. I'm not sure how it'll go since I'm in Korea right now. I've found an authorized service center that's pretty nice and my wife can translate, so hopefully they'll check it out or at least re-seat the card. I'll report back here after the weekend. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Good luck - I see why you were reluctant to take it back!
Definitely get it in before Applecare runs out - that makes it their problem rather than yours!
They've been very good here in Glasgow - I've had 2 hds fail and the Macbook cracking problem over the last 12 months and I've not had to put my hand in my pocket for a fix yet.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is. See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you said you solved the issue.

BUT FYI.  A USA bought Mac does not allow Wireless access on Channel 13.  A way round it is to use a repeater to make the wifi connection and then plug in the Mac to the repeater via cable (effectively a LAN connection)

Comment: Well, I was able to connect to a different router set to channel 13 without a problem. And my wife's Macbook was able to connect to the problem router as well. So, at least these two Macbooks from 2007 were able to connect to two different routers set to channel 13. Maybe that's only the newer models?

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook 13" unibody that is unable to connect to Channel 13 on my DLink DIR-655 wireless router. Only just figured it out as I was previously unable to connect the router at all. Just changed the router so that it permanently connects at Channel 10.